# WAMP server switch MySQL to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, wamp, mariadb, wampserver

How can I switch the database from MySQL to MariaDB in WAMP 3.1.0?

I'm looking for it, but I can not find it.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more context about what you want to achieve?

Comment: That option is there and I want to try it out

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the image you show it looks like both MySQL and MariaDB are already running!

NOTE: Thats a bit memory hungry!

Simple test to see if both MySQL and MariaDB are running. Launch phpMyAdmin and look at the login screen. If both are running you should see a **Server Choise** dropdown under the Username and Password fields. In there you will see 2 options like below.

[image]

To pick MySQL or MariaDB, **right click** on the wampmanager icon in the system tray and you should see this this menu

[image]

Just click on either MySQL or MariaDB to Enable or Disable either or both database servers. If there is a green tick beside the database server name, like above against MySQL, then that database server is configured to run, and if no tick exists, that server is not configured to run.

Alternatively, just look at the `services.msc` snap-in to see if the database server is a) installed and b) running (started)

> *Small note* WAMPServer is now at V3.1.2, [the update can be found here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) This contains a fix that if I remember correctly, contains a relevant fix. This is the WAMPServer backup repo, but it is a lot easier to navigate than SourceForge and is often more up to date than SourceForge as Oto does not have to jump through all the SourceForge loops to keep it up to date.
>
> Also note: that MariaDB and MySQL cannot both run on the same port i.e. 3306. So by default MySQL runs on 3306 and MariaDB runs on 3307. When you come to write PHP code you will have to specify port 3307 on your database connection code to make the connection to MariaDB if you are going to run both at the same time.
>
> Alternatively, if you want to use just MariaDB, Turn off MySQL and then switch MariaDB to use port 3306. There are menu items that make it quite easy if you look for them.

Comment: changing port to `3307` in `.env` file of my Laravel installation, worked for me. +1'ed.

Comment: But that means you will most likely have to change your .env when you move the site LIVE. Thats rarely a good idea, you shoudl endeavour to make your test environment as much like the live env as possible