# XAMPP MySQL said: Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

MySQL was working fine and then for no reason I start getting this error whenever I open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

[image]

I spent hours here trying to find solutions but all what I've tried did not work.

can someone please help me?

I am using: XAMPP Version: 7.3.6

Thanks

config.inc.php file content

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Comment: Please restart your machine and open phpmyadmin

Comment: @SAVe done that and did not solve the problem

Comment: FYI, I uninstall and reinstall the MySQL again and the same thing keeps coming

Comment: Have you tried changing `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';` to `… = 'localhost';`?

Comment: Also it might be worth running `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user` if you can get in on the command line to check which users are available

Comment: As it's complaining about it, I'd drop the lines for `'controluser'` and `'controlpass'` too.. you shouldn't need them to login (you can reconfigure later if necessary)

Answer (score 18):

SOLUTION - TRIED AND TESTED.

open folder >> C:\xampp\mysql\bin
open file (edit) >> my.ini

Add this line

```
# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables   <<<--- Add this line
port=3306
```

Save file.

Restart XAMPP.
Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

And there you have it.

Comment: This worked for me. This happened to me after a power cut. It's happened before and I always needed to reinstall. Thanks

Comment: خانه همسایه ات آباد

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;   <--- change this
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;  <--- to this fixed the problem.
```

Note: there are other areas in localhost where you have to change the password manually. For example in "CD Collection" example. The password is hard coded there rather than picking it up from config.inc.php.

Comment: When changing the AllowNoPassword to false I get 2 errors: {Cannot connect: invalid settings.} and {phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Run this command

```
 mysqladmin -u root password 'mynewpassword'
```

Comment: this is what I am getting: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server'

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a security precaution. You could try adding a new administrator account:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559992/7528823

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but for some reasons when I start XAMPP control panel as Administrator I can connect to phpMyAdmin with no issues

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are a bit confusing as it mentions MariaDb server. There was a change to WAMP server recently to allow MariaDb, don't know if XAMPP did the same.
[WAMP server switch MySQL to MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813733/wamp-server-switch-mysql-to-mariadb)

Given that it works when you run as Administrator, I'd say it cannot access a settings file when run as normal. Can you check the permissions on config.inc.php?

When it does connect as administrator: 
do you have to enter your mySql username and password?
what do you see in the database panel?

Server: Local Databases (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8), example:

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered same problem a few minutes ago, i was sure i didnt need any configuration change so what i did was to clear cookies and site data from 127.0.0.1 (might be localhost instead, in your case) and it was solved!